# I get bad request when I use this string with socket

Tags: php, sockets, http-status-code-400

I am trying to implement Fire and Forget in PHP, and I use this code (found [here](https://chriswhite.is/coding/fire-and-forget-http-requests-in-php/)):

```
$parts = parse_url($url);
try {
    $socket = $this->openSocket($parts['host'], ($parts['port'] ?? $parts['scheme'] === 'https' ? 443 : 80));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $socket = null;
}

if (!$socket) {
    return false;
}

$jsPostData = json_encode($postData, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

$contentLength = strlen($jsPostData);

$request = "POST {$parts['path']} HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$request .= "Host: {$parts['host']}\r\n";
$request .= "Authorization: Bearer " . $bearerToken . "\r\n";
$request .= "Content-Length: {$contentLength}\r\n";
$request .= "Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n";
$request .= $jsPostData;

fwrite($socket, $request);
fclose($socket);
```

It results with a request like this:

```
POST /my_path HTTP/1.1
Host: my_url
Authorization: Bearer my_bearer_token
Content-Length: 263
Content-Type: application/json

{"event":"...."}
```

I get the error:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: awselb/2.0
Date: Fri, 06 Oct 2023 09:43:17 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 220
```

I do not know if its a really bad request or its a permissions fail.

**UPDATE**

If I use this code with Guzzle it works:

```
try {
    $guzzle = new Client();
    $guzzle->post($url, [
        'timeout' => 1,
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => "Authorization: Bearer " . $bearerToken,
        ],
        'form_params' => $postData
    ]);
} catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException $e) {
    // do nothing, the timeout exception is intended
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're not using a ready-made HTTP client for this, such as cURL or Guzzle? Why the raw socket connection?

Comment: `or its a permissions fail`...normally a HTTP server should return 403 if there's a permissions issue. 400 means there was something it didn't understand in your request, or that wasn't valid. Of course, we don't know what the remote server is _expecting_ you to send. Have you tried to make the same request in something like Postman, to check you've basically set the request up correctly?

Comment: Getting `Content-Length: 220` suggests there's a response body as well. Perhaps it contains useful information about why your request is invalid. (Or maybe not.)

Comment: @ADyson I need a fire and forget connection, cause I do not need the response from the server

Comment: @ADyson the same request (I mean with the same parameters), works if I use Guzzle

Comment: I'm looking at this: `$parts['scheme'] === 'https' ? 443 : 80`. I'm not superfamiliar with raw sockets but, doesn't this mean you need to encrypt connection data yourself if scheme happens to be https?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I am not superfamiliar either. Every code I found on the web, seems to use this syntax to send data.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I'm not sure either, but I think it was failing due to some HTTPS/TLS problem it wouldn't have returned a clear response like this.

Comment: `the same request (I mean with the same parameters), works if I use Guzzle`...can you show us? Then we can check they really are exactly the same. And what response do you get to that - what counts as "working"?

Comment: @ADysonI updated the answer

Comment: Thanks. So...why exactly do you consider these two requests to be equivalent? In the socket version you are clearly sending 2 extra headers which are not present in the Guzzle version. Also in Guzzle you are using the `form_params` option to set the data, which - [as per the documentation](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#form-params) sends the data in form-url-encoded format to the server. Yet in the socket version you are sending JSON instead. I could be wrong, but you don't seem to understand the basic elements of the structure of the HTTP request you're sending.

Comment: @ADyson Yeah, sure, I didn't imply that HTTPS is the problem here, just that it's something that needs being implemented given that code appears to expect it, and the typical thing that works on my machine and fails when deployed to Production. As you said, a regular HTTP client would take care of all these details.

Comment: What I still don't get is, why haven't you shared the server response body? Is it because you don't know how to read it, or because you don't think it provides relevant information?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález both. I am not sure I am able to ready it correctly, so I think I could miss so information

Comment: @GiacomoM out of interest, how/where are you seeing the current 400 response you've shown us? As you said yourself it's a fire-and-forget request. Unless I'm wrong I don't see anything in the PHP which tries to collect it.

Comment: Anyway I think my earlier comment makes clear what the issue is likely to relate to - the server doesn't expect or want you to send JSON content, would be my assumption. Send form-url-encoded content instead, like in the Guzzle version.

Comment: @ADyson for testing I added the code the get the response. When I will be sure the code works, I will remove the response. I am trying to send the data in form-url-encoded content, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the socket version you are clearly sending 2 extra headers which are not present in the Guzzle version. Also in Guzzle you are using the `form_params` option to set the data, which - [as per the documentation](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#form-params) sends the data in form-url-encoded format to the server. Yet in the socket version you are sending JSON instead.

You should make the socket-based query send form-url-encoded data. This should work:

```
//sample data
$url = "https://www.example.com/postSomeData";
$postData = ["event" => "xyz", "someOtherField" => "abc"];
//end of sample

$contentType =  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
$params = http_build_query($postData);
$parts = parse_url($url);

try {
    $socket = $this->openSocket($parts['host'], ($parts['port'] ?? $parts['scheme'] === 'https' ? 443 : 80));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $socket = null;
}

if (!$socket) {
    return false;
}

$request = "POST {$parts['path']} HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$request .= "Host: {$parts['host']}\r\n";
$request .= "Content-Type: $contentType\r\n\r\n";
$request .= $params;

//echo($request);

fwrite($socket, $request);
fclose($socket);
```

This would generate a request as follows:

```
POST /postSomeData HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

event=xyz&someOtherField=abc
```

Simulation: https://3v4l.org/SY6cp

Other reference material:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php
- https://medium.com/@rajajawahar77/content-type-x-www-form-urlencoded-form-data-and-json-e17c15926c69